# Php change mulitple sections in a word to a pre-defined value

Tags: php

I am trying to add dynamic content to HTML to create a dynamic email template.

So in my HTML I have

```
    $html = '<b>Its a html {name} content email {email} here</b>';
```

I would like to replace the value of the {name} and {email} in my HTML such that

```
$arraydata = ["name"=>"Allan","email"=>"al@al.com"];
```

So how do I proceed so that the final HTML to be attached to the HTML body will be

```
'<b>Its a html Allan content email al@al.com here'
```

I have tried

```
$newHtml = "";
foreach ($keyvals as  $key=>$val){
        //itereate through html file and replace keys with values
        //am stuck on how to replace all keys and create the above.
        //the keys above can be many 
    }
return $newHtml;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would proceed like that:

```php
$html = '<b>Its a html {name} content email {email} here</b>';
$arraydata = ["name"=>"Allan","email"=>"al@al.com"];

foreach ($arraydata as $key => $value) {
    $html = str_replace('{' . $key . '}', $value, $html);
}

return $html;
```

Return value is:

```php
"<b>Its a html Allan content email al@al.com here</b>"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code which will replace if there is multiple appearance of the placeholders as below:

```
var replaceAll = function(string, replacingItem, replaceWith) {
   return string.toString().replace(new RegExp(replacingItem, 'g'), replaceWith);
};

$html = '<b>Its a html {name} content email {email} here</b>';
$arraydata = ["name"=>"Allan","email"=>"al@al.com"];

foreach ($arraydata as $key => $value) {
    $html = replaceAll($html, '{' . $key . '}', $value);
}

return $html;
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

In such scenario, I would do

```
    $arraydata = ["name"=>"Allan","email"=>"al@al.com"];
    echo $html = '<b>Its a html '. $arraydata['name'].' content email '. $arraydata['email'].' here</b>';
```

OUTPUT : Its a html Allan content email al@al.com here